# Cannot assign "[u'192.168.99.1', u'192.168.99.1']": "MultiWAN.nameserver" must be a "NameServer" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Consider the following django model

```
class MultiWAN(models.Model):

    isp_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description  = models.TextField(null=True)
    ip_address   = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    subnet       = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    gateway      = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    nameserver   = models.ForeignKey('NameServer')
    weight       = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    interface    = models.CharField(max_length=5) 



class NameServer(models.Model):
    """  A Isp can have more than one nameserver so far we are declearing a seperate table 
    """         
    name = models.IPAddressField(null=False)
```

I have written a corresponding view to take the userr input and save into db

```
def multiwan_info_save(request):

  #  try:
        isp_nm = request.POST['ispname_mw']
        desc_mw  = request.POST['desc_mw']
        ip_address_mw  = request.POST['ip_address_mw']
        subnet_mw = request.POST['subnet_mw']
        nameserver_mw = request.POST.getlist('nameserver_mw')
       # nameserver2_mw = request.POST['nameserver2_mw']
        gateway_mw = request.POST['gateway_mw']
        weight_mw = request.POST['weight_mw']
        interface_mw = request.POST['interface_mw']
        print "+++++++++++++++================="
        print nameserver_mw
        nmservr = NameServer()
        mv = MultiWAN(isp_name=isp_nm,description=desc_mw,ip_address=ip_address_mw,subnet = subnet_mw,gateway=gateway_mw,weight=weight_mw,interface = interface_mw,nameserver = nameserver_mw)

        mv.save()
    #except:
```

while i am trying to save i am getting the above error .Please help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: You should be using a ModelForm.

Answer (score 2):

You defined MultiWAN.nameserver as a foreign key on the NameServer model, so you need to pass a single NameServer instance to MultiWAN, ie:

```
nameserver = NameServer.objects.create(name="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
mv = MultiWan.objects.create(nameserver=nameserver, ....)
```

Now given that you're passing a list of IP address, I guess you got the MultiWAN / NameServer relationship wrong - looks like you want NameServer to have a foreign key on MultiWAN instead.

As a side note: you should really use a Form (or ModelForm) instead, as it will sanitize most of the inputs and take care of validation.

Answer (score 0):

As bruno says, you must pass a NameServer object because you declare the fields as ForeignKeys, but also consider to check before if the NameServer exists. A good practice for this is to use [objects.get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead of create.

```
nameserver, is_new = NameServer.objects.get_or_create(name='...')
```

This way you receive the nameserver instance and is_new would be True or False depending if the object was created or not.